# How can I reference/get the value from a cell from another column, but the cell is above a number of blank cells? See image

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying get the value of the previous cell from another column. But it must be the last cell above the current row.

[image]

Comment: Your question must be either related to `Google Sheets` or `Excel`.

Comment: Google sheets then

Comment: be careful you are not asking an xy Problem: 
https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`index`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) and [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to return the last cell above the current row with following formula:

```
=index(QUERY($B$2:$B2,"Select B where B is not null"),COUNT($B$2:B2))
```

[image]

If combined with [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) and [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en), you can make this independent of current row:

```
=index(QUERY(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW()),"Select B where B is not null"),COUNT(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW())))
```

#### Reference:

- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)

Comment: Why different casing, "index" and "QUERY"? Isn't there a convention for using one or the other (not a rhetorical question)?